# FatalExeption Error in LogCat

Tags: java, android, logcat

I don't know why I'm getting this error, I've spent about two hours trying to locate the source, but I just keep going round in circles. Could you have a quick look and see anything wrong?

WakeLock Code:-

```
wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON, "GLGame");
```

Here's the LogCat output:-

```
11-02 22:07:19.114: D/SensorGUI(517): SensorChannel(const Parcel& data): mSendFd = -1,          mReceiveFd = 55
11-02 22:07:19.114: D/SensorManager(517): [SensorManager] registerListener: delay = 20000
11-02 22:07:19.565: D/AndroidRuntime(517): Shutting down VM
11-02 22:07:19.565: W/dalvikvm(517): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception    (group=0x40abf228)
11-02 22:07:19.615: E/AndroidRuntime(517): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-02 22:07:19.615: E/AndroidRuntime(517): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start   activity ComponentInfo{com.an.chess/com.an.chess.ChessGame}:    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
11-02 22:07:19.615: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2194)
11-02 22:07:19.615: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2229)
11-02 22:07:19.615: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
11-02 22:07:19.615: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1261)
11-02 22:07:19.615: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-02 22:07:19.615: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
11-02 22:07:19.615: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
11-02 22:07:19.615: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-02 22:07:19.615: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-02 22:07:19.615: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
11-02 22:07:19.615: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
11-02 22:07:19.615: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native  Method)
11-02 22:07:19.615: E/AndroidRuntime(517): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
11-02 22:07:19.615: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock.<init>(PowerManager.java:250)
11-02 22:07:19.615: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at android.os.PowerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.java:446)
11-02 22:07:19.615: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at com.an.framework.impl.AndroidGame.onCreate(AndroidGame.java:50)
11-02 22:07:19.615: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4531)
11-02 22:07:19.615: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
11-02 22:07:19.615: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2150)
11-02 22:07:19.615: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  ... 11 more
```

Here's my Manifest file:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.an.chess"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="Chester" android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name=".ChessGame"
              android:label="Chess"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>  
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="8"/>
```

Thank you in advance for your kind support all the time!

Comment: You have a bug in your `newWakeLock()` call, apparently. You might consider updating your question with the source code where you are making this call.

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you for your help, I've updated the question, it doesn't show an error in Eclipse though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the creation of the `WakeLock` instance. From the android sources (API 14):

```
WakeLock(int flags, String tag)
{
    switch (flags & LOCK_MASK) {
    case PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK:
    case SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK:
    case SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK:
    case FULL_WAKE_LOCK:
    case PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK:
        break;
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    mFlags = flags;
    mTag = tag;
    mToken = new Binder();
}
```

So the flags you pass to `android.os.PowerManager.newWakeLock` are invalid.

**Update:**

You must use any of the above flags (e.g. `PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK`). You are using a `LayoutParam` constant which is unrelated to `WakeLock`.

Comment: Could the error be because I am targeting android API 8, rather than 14?

Comment: No, please look at my updated answer. Use one of the constants defined in `PowerManager`. API 8 supports `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK`, `FULL_WAKE_LOCK`, `SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK`, `SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK`, `ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP` and `ON_AFTER_RELEASE`.

Comment: YES! It worked! I've got more errors that have popped up, but they;re completely unrelated to this problem (apparently it can't find an image I've referenced - should be easy to resolve). THANK YOU for your help!